# How to find time complexity of the data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a queue. It has 'm' number of elements and there are 'n' number of duplicate elements. Now i want to copy the elements to Set, So what will be the time complexity to transfer elements in Queue to Set?

Comment: There is no such thing as "time complexity of data structures". We can only speak of the complexity of *algorithms* on a specific data structure.

Answer (score 0):

First find the complexity of dequeuing  m elements out of the queue, the complexity is dependent of the implementation.
Then find the complexity of adding those elements to the set, again the complexity is dependent of the implementation. 
A decent implementation of either data structure should approach O(1) for every operation (removing from queue and adding to set)

Answer (score 0):

The naive algorithm takes items from the queue and compares them to a list of unique elements and adds them if they're not in that list.
Call u=m-n being the number of unique elements (u>0 if and only if m>0).

In the worst case this requires u*(u+1)/2+n*u comparisons. That's when the list has all the unique elements at the start and a tail of duplicates. For example {5,11,7,9,9,9}.

Substituting back we get (m-n)*(m-n+1)+n*(m-n) = m^2−mn+m−n. That is O(m^2) because n

However if you can define a hashing function and push the elements into a hash map you can achieve performance of O(m) for practical finite values of m. Adding elements to an unsaturated hash map is O(1) and we do that O(m) times.

Another approach is to put the lot in a list and sort it then dump the duplicates (assuming you can define an ordering function on the elements). That is O(m*log(m)).

NB: The assumption here is that removing elements from the queue is O(1) - a fair assumption for any practical queue implementation.